# Why does wrong work on GetResponseStream in other Visualstudio version(2003->2012) in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to bring images as byte from web server and
i have this code that work in VisualStudio2003 but it doesn't work on VisualStudio2012 
both that birng different byte data using same code 
(both that byte code have different data length) 
Why did occur this situation ?
How to i bring right image by byte data ?

```
  Dim req As HttpWebRequest
        Dim stream As stream
        Dim reqs As HttpWebResponse
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        Dim outData() As Byte
        Dim ms2 As New MemoryStream

        path = "http://url.url.kr/FileRoot/Img.JPG"
        Try
            req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(path)
            reqs = req.GetResponse
            stream = reqs.GetResponseStream

            Dim buffer(128) As Byte


            While (True)
                Dim read As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                If read <= 0 Then
                    outData = ms.ToArray()
                    Exit While
                End If

                ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

            End While

            Dim memStr As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(outData)

            'ERROR!!  outData is wrong data 
            Dim image As New Bitmap(memStr)


            If path.ToUpper().IndexOf("PNG") > -1 Then
                image.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            ElseIf path.ToUpper().IndexOf("GIF") > -1 Then
                image.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
            Else
                image.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            End If

            Return ms2.ToArray()
```

Comment: Why dont you just do  `Dim image As New Bitmap(reqs.GetResponseStream())`?

Comment: `ms.Write(buffer, 0, read)`. The Buffer is **way too small**. You don't need to 2 MemoryStreams. You can also use `File.WriteAllBytes()`.

Comment: @Magnus Thank you! I solved my problem using your suggest

Comment: @Jimi thank you for your comment!